# Recursive pattern to take input integer and return palindrome

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I need to create a function that takes a single integer, and return results similar to:

```
pattern(0)
0
pattern(1)
010
pattern(2)
0102010
pattern(3)
010201030102010
and so forth....
```

The output must be a string and printed all on one line like above. 
I assume I need to use some type of recursive method and range function, but can't get past pattern(2) without hard coding. If someone can point me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the difference between each of the samples you've presented, and figure out how you could build each from the result of the previous.

Comment: The left side of the input == right side of input

Comment: Do you know how to write the pattern without using the computer? What's the fifth element of the pattern? What's the sixth? What steps are you taking to derive these results?

Comment: For every number 1..(2^(n+1)-1) write number of terminating zeroes in its binary representation

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code, tell us where it does not work (actual versus expected result, or error messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do what you need. 
Look at it as an example and see what your approach did differently.

```
#Start with a base case of 0 = "0" and fill in the results as they are computed
def n(x, m={0:'0'}):
    if x not in m:
        #Didn't have the answer, lets compute it.
        m[x] = '{0}{1}{0}'.format(n(x-1), x)

    #Look up what the answer is because we already computed it
    return m[x]

for x in range(5):    
    print(n(x))
```

Results in:

```
0
010
0102010
010201030102010
0102010301020104010201030102010
```

To handle the case of integers greater than 9 you can try something like this:

```
def n(x, m={0:'0'}):
    if x not in m:
        lX = x
        if x > 9:
            lX = str(x)
            #Take the integer like 123, format it and swap 
            #it but share the last character. i.e. 123 -> 12321
            lX = '{}{}'.format(x,lX[::-1][1:])

        m[x] = '{0}{1}{0}'.format(n(x-1), lX)
    return m[x]
```

Comment: If you reverse the condition of your `if`, you can put the recursive call and assignment to `m[x]` in there, then unconditionally `return m[x]` at the end. That structure is also good if you want an iterative version. Just make `m` is a list (initially `["0"]`) and append as many new values as necessary in a loop before returning `m[x]`: `while x >= len(m): m.append("{0}{1}{0}".format(m[-1], len(m)))`

Comment: Good point on swapping the if condition. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic recursive solution. It uses the same approach as [rdp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25411195/1405065), but without the memoization (which is probably unnecessary, since we only need to recurse once, and the palindrome structure breaks down when you get above `n=9`):

```
def reflected_palindrome(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "0" # base case

    return "{0}{1}{0}".format(reflected_palindrome(n-1), n)
```

This uses string formatting to assemble the results in the recursive case. The result of the recursive call is repeated twice, since the format string refers to `{0}` twice.

Comment: You can use something like: '{}{}'.format(10,str(10)[::-1][1:]) to turn a 10 into 101 and maintain the palindrome structure for ints larger than 9.